# Nginx Can't find Source Directory

Tags: nginx

I can't seem to find nginx's source directory on ubuntu 14.04, I would like to add other modules, i.e. `./configure --add_module`, I thought it would be `/etc/nginx/` but apparently not... Where could it be?

-- Edit

I used `locate nginx` this is what appeared:

```
/etc/nginx
/etc/default/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/nginx/conf.d
/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
/etc/nginx/koi-utf
/etc/nginx/koi-win
/etc/nginx/mime.types
/etc/nginx/naxsi-ui.conf.1.4.1
/etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
/etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/etc/nginx/proxy_params
/etc/nginx/scgi_params
/etc/nginx/sites-available
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params
/etc/nginx/win-utf
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
/etc/rc0.d/K20nginx
/etc/rc1.d/K20nginx
/etc/rc2.d/S20nginx
/etc/rc3.d/S20nginx
/etc/rc4.d/S20nginx
/etc/rc5.d/S20nginx
/etc/rc6.d/K20nginx
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service
/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx
/home/cae/.linuxbrew/Library/Formula/nginx.rb
/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service
/usr/sbin/nginx
/usr/share/nginx
/usr/share/doc/nginx
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common
/usr/share/doc/nginx-core
/usr/share/doc/nginx/CHANGES.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/nginx/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx/copyright
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/CHANGES.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/nginx-common/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/nginx-core
/usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
/usr/share/nginx/html
/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html
/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-core_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.4.6-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb
/var/lib/nginx
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-common.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-core.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-core.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-core.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx-core.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/nginx.md5sums
/var/lib/nginx/body
/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi
/var/lib/nginx/proxy
/var/lib/nginx/scgi
/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/nginx.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/multi-user.target.wants/nginx.service
/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: try to "Locate"  it eg -->>   locate nginx

Comment: Did you build from source?

Comment: It would be default to `/usr/local/nginx` if you didn't specify the `--prefix` option when configuring

Comment: You have to download it. `apt-get source nginx`

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to:

```
/var/nginx/nginx-0.0.0/src/http/
```

Instead of the 0.0.0 put your nginx Version in.